# $_POST and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'

Tags: php, post

i am using lot of Ajax in my PHP application, and typically to route the POST request for processing i check for an expected variable and a value and based on that i process the script.

For example if i want to delete or insert something using AJAX my typical PHP file that will process the POST request will be like

```
//Initialize the class on top of the page that will be dealing with CRUD functions.
$class = new CRUD();
//Delete Something
if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 'delete-something') {
    //Delete logic.
}
//Save Something
if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 'save-something') {
    //Save logic.
}
```

and so on. i was just wondering if the code `if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 'delete-something')` will give me protection against unauthorized request. or should i be using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` along the condition. is there really any difference between the two? because i saw lots of fellow developers using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` along.

Comment: What do you mean with unauthorized? That code won't do any authorization/authentication check.

Comment: My understanding is that if you sanitize any user input, and use POST for something like this -> you are minimizing the potential for unauthorized requests.

Comment: The superglobal variables are always "set", so `isset($_POST)` is true, regardless of whether the current request was actually done via POST or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTTP request it not a POST request, [`$_POST`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) would not be filled with actual values, so it's technically not necessary to check whether or not the request is a POST request if you test for a specific value.

However, you sometimes just want to know w/o testing for concrete values in the `$_POST` superglobal array, therefore, checking the server variable [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) can make sense.

So: It depends on context what you need to do.

Comment: can someone actually send a remote POST request to my script? as i will be using a different file for processing Ajax request. what i do is only check for some expected variable and process the value. am i being open to security threat?

Comment: Sure, that's just a standard HTTP request. How do you think the browser is doing that? Just the standard way. (Sure was jfor the request, not open to security. Security is a very vague term, so I can't tell you if there is a security risk or not in your application. I guess it needs to process HTTP requests, so I guess it's fine)

Comment: oh, so is it better if i cross check the script with sessions variables?

Comment: If you want to only allow authenticated users, then you might want to make use of a session of some kind. Sounds OK in my ears.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the least, doing this ...

```
if (isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 'delete-something')
```

... will prevent a NOTICE in the case where `$_POST['option']` does not exist. So, you'll probably still want to use `isset($_POST['option'])` even when using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'`.

Answer (score 0):

> I was just wondering if the code `if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 'delete-something')` will give me protection against unauthorized request.

Surely no.
I do not understand why do you think it can give any protection and what do you mean under "unauthorized request".

> Should i be using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` along the condition. Is there really any difference between the two?

Sure.
`$_POST['option'] == 'delete-something'` is checking the certain field while
`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` is checking the request method.
You simply can't use the latter one in place of former one. I do not understand this question either.